# Как добавить колонку с нумерацией в таблицу созданную с помощью f строк

Tags: python

```
Driver = namedtuple('Driver', 'driver_id, name, team, lap_time')
drivers = [Driver(driver_id='SVF', name='Sebastian Vettel', team='FERRARI', lap_time='0:01:04.415000'),
           Driver(driver_id='VBM', name='Valtteri Bottas', team='MERCEDES', lap_time='0:01:12.434000'),
           Driver(driver_id='SVM', name='Stoffel Vandoorne', team='MCLAREN RENAULT', lap_time='0:01:12.463000')]
columns = ['ID', 'Racer', 'Team', 'Time']
# расчёт максимальной длинны колонок
max_columns = []
for col in zip(*drivers):
    len_el = []
    [len_el.append(len(el)) for el in col]
    max_columns.append(max(len_el))

# печать таблицы с колонками максимальной длинны строки
# печать шапки таблицы
for n, column in enumerate(columns):
    print(f'|{column:{max_columns[n]+1}}', end='')
print()
# печать разделителя шапки '-'
r = f'{"-"*sum(max_columns)+"-"*9}'
print(r)

# печать тела таблицы
for el in drivers:
    for n, col in enumerate(el):
        print(f'|{col:{max_columns[n]+1}}', end='')
    print()
```

Вот что получаю на выходе:

```latex
|ID  |Racer             |Team            |Time            
---------------------------------------------------------- 
|SVF |Sebastian Vettel  |FERRARI         |0:01:04.415000  
|VBM |Valtteri Bottas   |MERCEDES        |0:01:12.434000  
|SVM |Stoffel Vandoorne |MCLAREN RENAULT |0:01:12.463000
```

необходимо слева добавить колонку: в шапку №, в тело нумерацию

Comment: Ваш код в студию.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил, надеюсь так как нужно?)

Comment: Ну вот хоть что-то :) Правда импортов не хватает ну это уже мелочи.

Comment: @СергейШ извиняюсь учусь только)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
# tmp = ""
# for n, column in enumerate(columns):
#     tmp += f' |{column:{max_columns[n]+1}}'
# print(f'№ {tmp}')
r = f'{"-"*sum(max_columns)+"-"*9}'
print(f'№ {"".join(f" |{column:{max_columns[n]+1}}" for n, column in enumerate(columns))}\n{r}')
    
for i, el in enumerate(drivers,1):
    tmp = ""
    for n, col in enumerate(el):
        tmp += f' |{col:{max_columns[n]+1}}'
    print(f'{i} {tmp}')
```

Comment: работает)) спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

`pip install tabulate`

```
from collections import namedtuple
from tabulate import tabulate

Driver = namedtuple('Driver', 'driver_id, name, team, lap_time')
drivers = [Driver(driver_id='SVF', name='Sebastian Vettel', team='FERRARI', lap_time='0:01:04.415000'),
           Driver(driver_id='VBM', name='Valtteri Bottas', team='MERCEDES', lap_time='0:01:12.434000'),
           Driver(driver_id='SVM', name='Stoffel Vandoorne', team='MCLAREN RENAULT', lap_time='0:01:12.463000')]
columns = ['№', 'ID', 'Racer', 'Team', 'Time']

print(
    tabulate(
        drivers,
        headers=columns,
        tablefmt='simple',
        showindex=range(1, len(drivers) + 1)
    )
)

# №   ID    Racer              Team             Time
# --  ----  -----------------  ---------------  --------------
#  1  SVF   Sebastian Vettel   FERRARI          0:01:04.415000
#  2  VBM   Valtteri Bottas    MERCEDES         0:01:12.434000
#  3  SVM   Stoffel Vandoorne  MCLAREN RENAULT  0:01:12.463000
```

> вобщем там много настроек и форматы вывода разные
> https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

К примеру формат `pipe` на печати будет выглядеть так

```latex
|   № | ID   | Racer             | Team            | Time           |
|----:|:-----|:------------------|:----------------|:---------------|
|   1 | SVF  | Sebastian Vettel  | FERRARI         | 0:01:04.415000 |
|   2 | VBM  | Valtteri Bottas   | MERCEDES        | 0:01:12.434000 |
|   3 | SVM  | Stoffel Vandoorne | MCLAREN RENAULT | 0:01:12.463000 |
```

А здесь  вот так:

| № | ID | Racer | Team | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SVF | Sebastian Vettel | FERRARI | 0:01:04.415000 |
| 2 | VBM | Valtteri Bottas | MERCEDES | 0:01:12.434000 |
| 3 | SVM | Stoffel Vandoorne | MCLAREN RENAULT | 0:01:12.463000 |

Comment: Спасибо, особенно за ссылку

Comment: Да, это тоже классный метод, я и через Панду(pd.DataFrame) выводил, но вот как именно вручную, с помощью f строк это сделать ?